# Set nested mapped observable object back to null?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have 3 objects in an ajax call that I map using the mapping plugin

- An observable array of tables
- Each table has an observable array of seat
- Each seat may or may not have a player (nullable attribute)

I map like this (using a very simplified code sample), with most of the heavy lifting being done by the plugin, and then some computeds

```
var TableViewModel = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, codeMapping, self);
}

var SeatViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, codeMapping, self);    

    self.CssClass = ko.computed(function () {       
        if (ko.toJS(self.Player) != null)
           return "occupiedSeat";        
        return "";
   });
}

var PlayerViewModel = function (data) {
   var self = this;
   ko.mapping.fromJS(data, codeMapping, self);    
}

var codeMapping = {
   create: function (options) {
      return new ViewModel(options.data);
   }    
   'Players': {
      create: function (options) {
           return new PlayerViewModel(options.data);
       }
   },
   'Tables': {
       create: function (options) {
           return new TableViewModel(options.data);
       }
   }
   'Seats': {
       create: function (options) {
           return new SeatViewModel(options.data);
      }
   }
}
```

And the ajax looks like this

```
[{"TableId":1,"Seats":[{"SeatId":1,"Player":{"PlayerId":1}},{"SeatId":2,"Player":{"PlayerId":2}},{"SeatId":3,"Player":null}]}]
```

If i decide to move a player, say from seat 2 to seat 3, i add a click function to the UI element

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Seats">
   <div class="seat" data-bind="attr: { class: CssClass() }, click:MovePlayer">                                                              
   </div>
</div>

function MovePlayerToSeat() { 
   var oldSeat = this;
   var newSeat = someArrayFirstLookupMethod();
   $.post({"/api/movePlayer"})
    .done(function (playerObj) {
       newSeat.Player = ko.observable(new PlayerViewModel(playerObj));
       oldSeat.Player = ?????
   }
```

}

I can set the new object pretty easily, but (and i've searched high and low for this, and think it might not be possible?) i can't unset the existing observable Player back to null, so that it fails the condition in the SeatViewModel computed

```
if (ko.toJS(self.Player) != null)
```

I've tried

```
oldSeat.Player = null
//and
oldSeat.Player(null)
```

But the first one doesn't work and the second one (correctly) exceptions that Player isn't a function.

Is this possible in Knockout?

**EDIT:**

Adding extra context to answer question below

Possibly this doesn't line up, because in attempting to pare down my code, i might have misrepresented the problem. But this doesn't work, at least not for the question i'm asking.

If i do the mapping manually, setting each

```
self.attribute = ko.observable(data.attribute)
```

when the data is being loaded initially, this creates a different end result for null values than if i just called

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self).
```

For the former, if i do a

```
console.log(ko.toJS(self.Player()))
```

it spits out

```
{Object {PlayerId: 1, __ko_mapping__: Object}, Object {PlayerId: 2, __ko_mapping__: Object}, Object{}}
```

However, for the latter,

if i try call

```
console.log(ko.toJS(self.Player()))
```

It'll tell me *Uncaught TypeError: self.Player is not a function*. Instead i have to call

```
console.log(ko.toJS(self.Player))
```

Because mapping doesn't make the object an observable until it needs to, it keeps it null. So this produces

```
{Object {PlayerId: 1, __ko_mapping__: Object}, Object {PlayerId: 2, __ko_mapping__: Object}, null}
```

So setting it to null in the way you've mentioned doesn't work, as mapping doesn't make nested objects functions in the same way (i don't know if this is a bug or by design?).

This investigation has highlighted to me that there is a possible workaround by handling this object mapping manually, but i guess my question still is, is it possible to unmap/unset an observable so that it just exists as a property name, but no longer as an observable?

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the appropriate way to unset your oldSeat Player. Because `ko.observable` objects are actually functions.

```
oldSeat.Player(null);
```

[Reading and writing observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: I've added extra context to my question to address your response